# Moving cells to a specific sheets meeting a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a VBA that moves rows of cells into specific sheets. Basically have all the data on one worksheet and it copies the rows into the worksheet it belongs too.

[image: Screenshot of Data]

The identifier is the first two digits before the hyphen in the invoice number.

For example,

Every row that has an invoice number starting with "1-" will get pasted into sheet 2

Invoice "3-" will get pasted into sheet 3...etc

I was able to find some lines of code that will work, but i'm having a hard time finding the correct code to read the numbers before the hyphen.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "1-" Then

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

There are about 16 different invoice numbers identifiers, so I will have 16 different sheets it will paste it too.

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT()` with `SEARCH()/FIND()`? What have you tried to get the invoice number?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. I did look up the LEFT() command, but i'm not too sure how to implement it in the code. This is all new to me

Comment: Take a look at [some of these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+get+text+left+of+a+delimiter), you should find the solution to get the info left of the `-` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this:

```
Dim dashpos As Long
```

Add this line before copying it according to your data if I have put in wrong information. This will get the data to the left of `-` and you can put it in the worksheet you need. The number on the left will be extracted and put in column 4 and then you can compare the number there.

```
dashpos = InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "-")
Cells(I, 4).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1), dashpos - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Building upon what Snehil said, try using this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim dashpos As Long

For i = 2 To a

dashpos = InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "-")
Cells(i, 4).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1), dashpos - 1)

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = "1" Then

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

I believe there's an error where you're defining 'b', see my suggestion above.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered turning this into a table, then just using power query to move the data? Is there a reason VBA needs to be used for this?

Comment: First time hearing about power query. I'll try it out now. No real reason to use VBA, at the time I thought it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Power Query is amazing for most "light" data movements - IE, if you don't need to completely reformat data locations, it's usually good enough. I'm actually in the middle of refactoring a VBA statement to be a power query statement